# SweetAlert2 crappy text

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I have a question about [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).
As you can see in this picture that's how my swal2 looks, but on the official site or others the text is smoother, how should I fix this? Maybe I've forgot one CSS/JS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert2.css">
    <script>
function myFn(){
swal(
  'Succes!',
  'Mesajul a fost trimis cu succes!',
  'success'
)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/jnoula
   Github / JSFiddle: http://prntscr.com/jnovyf

```
 <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                myFn();
                </script>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SweetAlert2 doesn't define font-family but **inherits it from the document**. The reason is that alerts should look consistent with the rest of the page.

Define the `font-family` for your page and you'll be fine :)

Demo with Ubuntu typeface:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'So beautiful yet terrific!',
  icon: 'success'
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```